# Re-open request - determining DLLs used by VB6 program

Tags: support, reopen-closed

This question was previously closed:
[Determine which DLL and/or OCX files are actually used by my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303331/how-i-can-see-the-dll-and-or-ocx-files-actually-used-by-my-program)

I have edited to try any clarify what I think was really being asked. The issue in this question is very much pertinent to VB6 developers (or people supporting old applications).

Although the original question was not well written or totally clear I'm not really sure why it was close-worthy in the first place. In any event, I hope I've cleared up the main issues it had.

Best regards

Comment: "My software is written in VB6." *checks date* That is amazing. Have a reopen vote.

Comment: hey, don't want to make it seem like just because you're maintaining legacy software platforms that your questions are unwelcome on Stack Overflow. Definitely worth a reopen vote.

Comment: The question is still off topic, as it's essentially asking for a tool. And, oh, look, the correct answer is a tool suggestion. No tho.

Comment: @will actually there is no tool (to my knowledge) which does what the OP wants. The answer that is there is incomplete IMO. A better answer would describe a process for the developer to follow. OF course that would involve using tools but is not so simple as to say "just run program XYZ". Such a process is useful in a customer support scenario but also very much for developers who have to deal with this technology still. There's plenty of debugging of configuration in VB6 which is partly what the question is getting at.

Comment: Op disagrees, obvs. Also, as far as I know, that tool will do what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Will Dependency Walker will not detect COM references because they are not statically linked to the program. Possibly in some cases DW might provide sufficient insight, but not in most cases by any means. The question specifically mentioned COM DLLs (of which OCXes are included). I don't know why he accepted the given answer.